# Is this a known Pythagorean result?

Tags: number-theory

Since the Pythagorean Theorem applies to right triangles, it can be stated:

In triangle $ABC$, the length of whose sides are $a$, $b$ and $c$, $a^2+b^2=c^2$ if and only if $\cos(\angle C)=0$.

I recently proved the following related result:

In triangle $ABC$, the length of whose sides are $a$, $b$ and $c$, $a(a+k)+b(b+k)=c(c+k)$ if and only if $\cos(\angle C)=−k/(a+b+c+k)$.

Is this a known result and, if so, where has it appeared?

Comment: It looks to me like it could probably be deduced from the law of cosines.

Comment: What exactly is $k$?

Comment: Wasn't this answered in a comment on MathOverflow? Yes, it's here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110712/is-this-generalization-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-a-known-result-and-if-so-wher

Comment: If you cross-post, please include a link to the other post so that effort isn't unnecessarily duplicated.